# Kripton database library limit select query

Tags: android, database, android-kripton

I try to use [Kripton database library](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton).
Everything is fine if I use select query with no limitation

```
@BindSqlSelect(orderBy="timestamp desc")
List<History_> selectAll();
```

But I have no idea how to limit select statement. How can I bind or add limit value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself. If we need to limit select in Kripton Library we can do it like this way

implement DAO

```
@BindSqlSelect(orderBy="timestamp desc")
PagedResult<History_> selectLimit(@BindSqlPageSize int pageSize);
```

and we can use it like this

```
        PagedResult<History_> result = dao.selectLimit(5);

        result.firstPage();
        List<History_> historyList = result.getList();
        for (History_ history : historyList) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a limit. All you can do is do something like:

```
@BindSqlSelect(orderBy="timestamp desc", pageSize = 20)
List<History_> selectAllPaginated();
```

Or call it like this:

```
@BindSqlSelect(orderBy="timestamp desc")
List<History_> selectAllPaginated(@PageSize int pageSize);
```

Comment: This one must be a good idea, but in my case I can't use @PageSize, because of "Cannot resolve symbol PageSize", and the same problem occurs with PaginatedResult. Well, I'm in stuck